# Detect citrix "application mode"?

Tags: delphi, citrix

Forgive me for probably using the wrong term for this "application mode".

Our application has a problem during start in that it doesn't show a task bar icon until the main window is up, even though there are loading progress windows, logon-windows, etc. on screen before that.

We change the code to fix this, but unfortunately this fix, when running the app through citrix, now shows two icons, one with just the icon and no text.

Is there a way for me to detect that the application is running through citrix? I don't know the right term for this, but only the app window is brought to the users desktop, not the whole remote desktop.

If it matters, the app is written in Delphi.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not sure exactly how to do this in delphi, but if you can call out to the user32.dll, and call the function:

```
if (GetSystemMetrics(SM_REMOTESESSION) != 0)
{
   // We are in a remote session
}
```

This should tell you if you are running in a Citrix or Terminal Services environment.
SM_REMOTESESSION is defined as:

```
#define SM_REMOTESESSION        0x1000
```

More info on the GetSystemMetrics api here:
[Link to msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724385.aspx)

**Edit**
The following page describes how to do exactly the above in delphi. What works for Terminal Services should also work for Citrix:

[Is your Delphi Application Running under Terminal Services as a Remote Session](http://delphi.about.com/od/delphitips2008/qt/isremotesession.htm)

Answer (score 6):

This works for me:

```
return System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.TerminalServerSession;
```

Answer (score 6):

A side-note for the curious: The solution proposed by "open-collar" is just a .NET wrapper for the one given by John Sibly. They should return the same result in every case. I confirmed this by disassembling the System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation class.